# Disable Screenshot-generation when creating a Cypress-Report

Tags: integration-testing, cypress

I using Cypress combined with mochawesome-report / mochareports for to generate reports automatically.

[image: screenshot]

I'm starting the tests by executing `npx cypress run --config video=false --browser chrome` on the terminal.

Screenshots shall **not** be created.

**Is there a flag, similar to `video=false`, concerning screenshots?**

**Or: How can I disable screenshot-generation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this in your configuration

> Capturing of screenshots when a test fails can be turned off entirely by setting screenshotOnRunFailure to false from within your configuration or by setting screenshotOnRunFailure to false in the Cypress.Screenshot.defaults().

- [Screenshots](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/screenshots-and-videos.html#Screenshots)